# unrecognized arguments: --on-shared-storage

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

We have tried to evacuate the instance with the "on-shared-storage" option but that parameter is not recognized. Please help me with this issue.

nova evacuate --on-shared-storage <<Instance_UUID>> <<host_name>>

Error:

error: unrecognized arguments: --on-shared-storage
Try 'nova help ' for more information.

Comment: Nova command line options have nothing to do with Horizon.

Comment: What version of Nova are you using?  Support for the 'onSharedStorage' flag was removed in Nova microversion 2.14.

Comment: [stack@undercloud (stackrc) ~]$ nova --version
6.0.2
[stack@undercloud (stackrc) ~]$

Comment: @StephenC how to enable the parameter flag

Comment: That is the version of your client.  What I am asking about is the API microversion of the Nova >>service<<; e.g. https://docs.openstack.org/nova/rocky/contributor/microversions.html

Comment: whats is the command for that version checks ?

Comment: DEFAULT_API_VERSION = "2.1"

Answer (score 1):

According to the Nova release notes, the `onSharedStorage` option is no longer necessary:

https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/master/releasenotes/notes/remove-on-shared-storage-flag-from-evacuate-api-76a3d58616479fe9.yaml

```
@gibizer
gibizer Remove onSharedStorage from evacuate API
Latest commit c01d16e on Nov 10, 2015
History
1 contributor
7 lines (7 sloc) 353 Bytes
---
features:
  - Remove ``onSharedStorage`` parameter from server's evacuate action in
    microversion 2.14. Nova will automatically detect if the instance is on
    shared storage. Also adminPass is removed from the response body which
    makes the response body empty. The user can get the password with the
    server's os-server-password action.
```

The fact that your `nova` client doesn't recognize the option implies that your Nova service's default microversion is later than 2.14.

You could try *forcing* the microversion, but there doesn't seem to be much point ... based on what the release note says.

(According to the current `python-novaclient` source code, the `--on-shared-storage` option is recognized for microversions 2.0 through 2.13.  See https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient/blob/master/novaclient/v2/shell.py)